# Suppose that $\{s_n\}$ is a convergent sequence. Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} 2s_n$ exists

Tags: real-analysis

Here's my proof for the question.

Proof: Suppose $\{s_n\}$ is convergent.

Let $\epsilon$ > 0 be given. By definition of a convergent sequence, $s_n \to L $ indicates that a positive integer *N* can be chosen such that, for all *n* > *N*, Thus,

$$ |s_n - L | < \epsilon .$$

Consider $a_n$ = $2s_n$. Then without loss of generality we have

$$ |a_n - L | < \epsilon .$$

In which case it follows that the limit exists. Therefore,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(2s_n)$$ exists.

My only concern is between  $$ |s_n - L | < \epsilon, $$

and the next sentence where a feel something needs to be added.

Comment: If $s_n$ is close to $L$, then $a_n=2s_n$ is not close to $L$.  You want it close to $2L$.

Comment: I noticed that, out of 4 questions asked, you have not yet accepted a single answer. While I am not trying to strong-arm you into accepting MY answer, I would like to ask that you go through your previously asked questions and select answers that have helped you. This rewards the people who have taken the time out of their busy lives to assist you with your question(s).

Comment: I apologize if I haven't responded to any of the comments, but yes I won't forget to do so.

Comment: You can accept an answer by pressing the check mark under the "Downvote button".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument can be made a lot easier. Let $s_n \to s$. Then, given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N$ so that

$$ |s_n - s| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} \Rightarrow |2s_n - 2s| < \epsilon$$

when $n \ge N$. Hence, $2s_n \to 2s$.

Comment: Thanks. This made more sense after you explained it.